# How can I use SonarQube web service API for reporting purpose

Tags: unix, sonarqube

I want to create a custom report. Response format for sonarqube web service API /api/issues/search is JSON or XML. How can I use that response to create a html or CSV file using "unix shell without using command line tools" so that I can use it as a Report. Or is there any other better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can generate a html file if you run an analysis in the preview mode http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6947686

Comment: Yes.. but the size of html issue report is too big to be attached in Email and lighter version is not useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

There at least two open-source projects that query the SQ API to generate reports in various formats.

- https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report/tree/dev (Java)
- https://github.com/soprasteria/sonar-report (JavaScript/Node)

At the time of writing both are active.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the SonarQube team has been working hard to not allow people to do this.  They appear to want people to purchase an Enterprise Subscription in order to export reports.

An old version of sonar-runner (now called sonar-scanner) had an option to allow local report output.  But that feature is "no more supported".

`ERROR: The preview mode, along with the 'sonar.analysis.mode' parameter, is no more supported. You should stop using this parameter.`

Looks like version 2.4 of Sonar Runner does what you want.  If you can find it.  Of course they only have 2.5RC1 available on the site now.

Using the following command should work on version 2.4:
`sonar-runner -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true`